# 'xx' is not a registered namespace in django

Tags: django, url, namespaces, reverse

there is a question about django url reversing...
'appA' and 'appB' are two apps in django,and both have been registered in root
'urls.py':

```
include(r'appA/',include('mysite.appA',namespace='appA')),
```

but in most of my templates,`{% url appA:app_view_one %}` would work, and in few pages,it doesn't work for `{% url appA:app_view_two %}`

i don't think it is because of app_view_two being wrong ,it works in other template.
and it may not because the django url syntax `{% load url from future %}` ,I've tried but still not work...

could someone help me or ever see similar question?

thanks!

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? What are the url patterns for `app_view_one` and `app_view_two`? If you've made a simple mistake, it's very possible that you haven't repeated it when you changed the names to `appA`, `app_view_on` in your question, so we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Show us urlpatterns of appA, appB

Answer (score 0):

Check `urls.py` in your Project's root directory.

Take notice of what before string 'url',"tab" or "space".

Consider using any one of them.